# debugging uwsgi/nginx (works on OpenBSD, doesn't on Linux)

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running an extremely simple piece of python code which runs flawlessly under OpenBSD (using httpd + uwsgi). The same code, with the same uwsgi configuration simply does not run under Linux (using nginx).

The code is [here](https://github.com/lorenzog/url-share/blob/master/url_share.py) while the `uwsgi.ini` file is [here](https://github.com/lorenzog/url-share/blob/master/uwsgi.ini) as well as below:

```
[uwsgi]
fastcgi-socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
uid = uwsgi
module = url_share
callable = parent_app
virtualenv = %d/venv
chdir = %d
# daemonize after loading app
daemonize2 = True
```

I'm assuming the problem is in nginx, which is the only changing variable over which I'd have some control. Its configuration is also extremely simple:

```
server {
        location /urlsh/ {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        }
```

In particular, nginx's error_log is:

```
2015/11/30 23:03:32 [error] 27894#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.107, server: , request: "GET /urlsh/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031", host: "192.168.1.10"
```

This happens exactly **8.1 seconds** after opening the page with a web browser:

```
    $ time curl 127.0.0.1/urlsh/
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center>
</body>
</html>

real    0m8.120s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.020s
```

My question is: how do I get uwsgi to print more output?

Things I've tried to pinpoint the problem:

- Adding `print` statements in the python code: they get printed, so the application runs
- Running the application as a stand-alone Python program: no problem under Linux
- Removing nginx, installing the default configuration

System is a Linux Raspbian 7.8 "Wheezy". Python is 2.7.3 and uwsgi (installed via pip) is 2.0.11.2.

Comment: Have you tried changing the fastcgi-socket to plain old 'socket'? I tend to use unix sockets in my configurations, but uwsgi will flow through a TCP socket just as happily.

Comment: The reasoning is that your nginx configuration is expecting UWSGI, but your uwsgi instance will be talking fast-cgi.

Comment: @MatiuCarr that was right - socket instead of fastcgi-socket solved it. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!!